# Bypassing Devise gem registration form to create a new user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I am usin devise gem and recaptch in rails project
can any one give me a hint:
how to create a new user bypassing recaptcha and without submitting a form of devise gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new controller by inheriting the `Devise::SessionsController` and override the action `register`.

For more details:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Answer (score 0):

There's an article on how to integrate devise & recaptcha in the Devise wiki docs here: [Devise Wiki: Hot to use Recaptcha with Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise).

Devise is a very popular gem and chances are if you have a question regarding it, somebody has asked it before so it's literally a [google search away](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Devise+rails+recaptcha).